# Painting polygons in ASP.NET

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, asp.net

I have this problem, I need to paint each polygon with a distinct color based on an atribute value using .NET, for example:

```
Polygon    value
1        10
2        10
3        5
4        5
5        1
```

Polygon 1 and 2 will be painted blue, polygon 3 and 4 will be green, and polygon 5 will be painted red

Does anyone knows how to do this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will you be doing this in ArcMap? Also, why did you select the ASP.Net tag? Is this a web-based application? If so, are you using any of ESRI's APIs?

Comment: hi michael, I'm not using arcmap, I have to do this in asp.net beacuse I'll be consuming an arcgis server service and I'm using the components installed in visual studio, got any tip?

Comment: So you're trying to consume an ArcGIS Server service using Visual Studio. Do you plan on using the SOAP API, Javascript API, or Silverlight API? And are these polygons already available in the service that you're consuming or are you adding them yourself?

Comment: I'll be using the javascript API mostly, the polygons are available in the service, I just have to paint them based on a value, also, I'm thinking on using flex to do this, wich way is easier? .NET or Flex?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework exposes GDI+ to you which in my opinion is a super easy way to do some simple drawing. The newer versions of .NET (3+) has some more features in the System.Windows.Media namespace. If your problem leans more towards needing GIS capabilities to parse the data there are some projects you can use such as SharpMap.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this doesn't help me at all, I have to use Arcgis Server only, with the tools they provide, thanks anyway